# Why does this SQL statement produce a wrong timestamp?

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, strftime

The statement

```
select strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', (select datetime('2019-07-24 11:11:59', '-288.0110592 seconds')), '+411.030309 seconds')
```

gives me the timestamp

```
2019-07-24 11:14:01.030
```

Verifying the result with Python, I noticed that the result is about one second off.

My Python code:

```
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-07-24 11:11:59', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
offset1 = datetime.timedelta(seconds=288.0110592)
offset2 = datetime.timedelta(seconds=411.030309)
result = start - offset1 + offset2
print(result.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

Output:

```
2019-07-24 11:14:02.019250
```

I did not expect the results to be exactly equal due to rounding errors, but why does the SQL statement seem to be off by almost a second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the inner select using `datetime`. As described in the [manual](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), `datetime(...)` is equivalent to `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', ...)`, and you'll note that the format of the seconds is `%S`, not `%f`, so the result of

```
datetime('2019-07-24 11:11:59', '-288.0110592 seconds')
```

is

```
2019-07-24 11:07:10.000
```

not the correct value (with fractional seconds) of

```
2019-07-24 11:07:10.989
```

Changing the `datetime(...)` call to `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', ...)` i.e.

```
strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', '2019-07-24 11:11:59', '-288.0110592 seconds')
```

yields the correct result.

Note that you can simplify the expression and use both modifiers in the outer call to `strftime`:

```
select strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', '2019-07-24 11:11:59', '-288.0110592 seconds', '+411.030309 seconds')
```

Output:

```
2019-07-24 11:14:02.019
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nMyJDRjUAFEwwsR4AgYJVj/0)

Comment: Thank you very much for the competent help. My follow up question has been resolved.